# chequear el IP de entrada con array de IP

Tags: php, array

Quiero chequear el IP de entrada si esta dentro de alguno de los 3 o 4 lista de array me ponga el mensaje, lo tenia echo asi pero no me funciona.

```
$laptop=(1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3)
$pcescritorio=(1.1.1.2,2.2.2.3,3.3.3.4)
switch ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
case "laptop":
    readfile("laptop.pdf");
    break;
case "pcescritorio":
    readfile("work.pdf");
    break;
default:
    echo "No Encontrado";
}
```

La idea es el que entre el chequee el IP con las lista de IP de mas arriba y le mande automaticamente el tipo de fichero segun el tipo de PC que tenga, los IP pueden variar y ser diversos eso me encargo yo de ponerselos, pero no logro que me funcione

Comment: Pedro tu pregunta no es clara, no se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres, por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164073/edit) explicándote mejor, para que podamos ayudarte. En cuanto a `$laptop` y `$pcescritorio` no son arrays como crees, deberías declararlos así, si quieres que sean arrays: `$laptop=array("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3");  $pcescritorio=array("1.1.1.2","2.2.2.3","3.3.3.4");` fíjate que he puesto cada valor encerrado entre comillas.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, tú tendrías dos arrays con direcciones IP, y quieres verificar si la IP obtenida con `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` está en uno de esos dos arrays.

Puedes intentarlo así:

```
/*Creamos dos arrays correctos con las IP*/
$laptop=array("1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3");
$pcescritorio=array("1.1.1.2","2.2.2.3","3.3.3.4");

/*Una variable para la IP actual, así el código queda más claro*/
$ipActual=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    

/*
  *Nos vamos a valer de dos operadores ternarios    
  *para determinar si $ipActual está en alguno de los arrays
  *cuando se cumpla alguno de ellos llamaremos a readfile con el nombre
  *si ninguno se cumple, imprimiremos el mensaje 
  *That's all!
 */

in_array($ipActual, $laptop) ? readfile("laptop.pdf") : 
    (
        in_array($ipActual, $pcescritorio) ? readfile("work.pdf"): print ("No encontrado")
    );
```

Esta opción hace uso de los Operadores Ternarios, para simplificar el código, si se te hace ilegible o difícil, te puedo proponer una solución más clásica también.